# I remove \n from string in C but the result is not what I need it to be

Tags: c, newline, string-literals, removing-whitespace, function-definition

I want to remove the '\n' from a string. Here's the code:

```
void remove_new_line(char* restrict str_trimmed, const char* restrict str_untrimmed)
{
    while (*str_untrimmed != '\0')
    {
        if (*str_untrimmed != '\n')
        {
            *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
            str_trimmed++;
        }
        str_untrimmed++;
    }
    *str_trimmed = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char * x = "cat a.txt | wc -l\n";
    printf(".%s.", x);

    char * y = (char*)malloc(100);
    remove_new_line(y, x);
    printf(".%s.", y);

    char * z = "cat a.txt | wc -l";
    printf(".%s.", z);
}
```

The result of the first print is

.cat a.txt | wc -l
.

The result of the second print is

.cat a.txt | wc -l

And the result of the third print is

.cat a.txt | wc -l.

How is string y (the one that I create with remove_new_line) different from string z? It must be different somehow, since it prints differently. I need to modify remove_new_line function (or create a new function) so that the second print is identical with the third print, and string y and z are identical.

Comment: You're probably on Windows and there's a \r as well

Comment: Change the last character printed from `.` to something else that is not going to be printed. It will be a more informative test.

Comment: @Barbara Show the three outputs as one output.

Comment: @user253751 Oh wow! Thanks! I never heard of this... And I've been trying to fix this for three hours... Thank You :)

Comment: you might want to read up on the function: `strcspn()`  and use it like:  `buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your output. If to run this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_new_line(char* restrict str_trimmed, const char* restrict str_untrimmed)
{
    while (*str_untrimmed != '\0')
    {
        if (*str_untrimmed != '\n')
        {
            *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
            str_trimmed++;
        }
        str_untrimmed++;
    }
    *str_trimmed = '\0';
}

int main(void) {

    char * x = "cat a.txt | wc -l\n";
    printf(".%s.", x);

    char * y = (char*)malloc(100);
    remove_new_line(y, x);
    printf(".%s.", y);

    char * z = "cat a.txt | wc -l";
    printf(".%s.", z);
    
    printf( "\ny == z is %d\n", strcmp( y, z ) == 0 );

    free( y );
}
```

then the output is

```
.cat a.txt | wc -l
..cat a.txt | wc -l..cat a.txt | wc -l.
y == z is 1
```

as you can see the dot is not skipped

```
.cat a.txt | wc -l
..cat a.txt | wc -l..cat a.txt | wc -l.
                   ^^
```

If you will run this program under Windows you will get the same result because neither character `'\r'` is present in the string literals.

Maybe instead of string literals you are using strings read from a file in your original program. In Windows strings can be written in a file with trailing `'\r'`, `'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was with the '\r' since I am on Windows. One small change in the if clause and everything is fine.

```
void remove_new_line(char* restrict str_trimmed, const char* restrict str_untrimmed)
{
    while (*str_untrimmed != '\0')
    {
        if (*str_untrimmed != '\n' && *str_untrimmed != '\r')
        {
            *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
            str_trimmed++;
        }
        str_untrimmed++;
    }
    *str_trimmed = '\0';
}
```